# How can I reuse common configuration across different kubernetes manifests?

Tags: kubernetes

Assume I have this manifest:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: initialize-assets-fixtures
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: wait-for-minio
        image: bitnami/minio-client
        env:
          - name: MINIO_SERVER_ACCESS_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: minio
                key: access-key
          - name: MINIO_SERVER_SECRET_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: minio
                key: secret-key
          - name: MINIO_SERVER_HOST
            value: minio
          - name: MINIO_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER
            value: "9000"
          - name: MINIO_ALIAS
            value: minio
        command: 
          - /bin/sh
          - -c 
          - |
            mc config host add ${MINIO_ALIAS} http://${MINIO_SERVER_HOST}:${MINIO_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER} ${MINIO_SERVER_ACCESS_KEY} ${MINIO_SERVER_SECRET_KEY}
      containers:
      - name: initialize-assets-fixtures
        image: bitnami/minio
        env:
          - name: MINIO_SERVER_ACCESS_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: minio
                key: access-key
          - name: MINIO_SERVER_SECRET_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: minio
                key: secret-key
          - name: MINIO_SERVER_HOST
            value: minio
          - name: MINIO_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER
            value: "9000"
          - name: MINIO_ALIAS
            value: minio
        command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - |
            mc config host add ${MINIO_ALIAS} http://${MINIO_SERVER_HOST}:${MINIO_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER} ${MINIO_SERVER_ACCESS_KEY} ${MINIO_SERVER_SECRET_KEY}

            for category in `ls`; do
              for f in `ls $category/*` ; do
                mc cp $f ${MINIO_ALIAS}/$category/$(basename $f)
              done
            done
      restartPolicy: Never
```

You see I have here one `initContainer` and one `container`. In both containers, I have the same configuration, i.e. the same `env` section.

Assume I have yet another `Job` manifest where I use the very same `env` section again.

It's a lot of duplicated configuration that I bet I can simplify drastically, but I don't know how to do it. Any hint? Any link to some documentation? After some googling, I was not able to come up with anything useful. Maybe with kustomize, but I'm not sure. Or maybe I'm doing it the wrong way with all those environment variables, but I don't think I have a choice, depending on the service I'm using (here it's minio, but I want to do the same kind of stuff with other services which might not be as flexible as minio).

Comment: [helm](https://helm.sh/) lets you template the yaml with values. Also once you get into it there are ways to create and include [partial templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my knowledge you have those 3 options

- [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/)
- [Helm](https://helm.sh/)
- [ConfigMap](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/ultimate-configmap-guide-kubernetes.html)

---

**ConfigMap**

---

You can use either kubectl create configmap or a ConfigMap generator in kustomization.yaml to create a ConfigMap.

The data source corresponds to a key-value pair in the ConfigMap, where

**key** = the file name or the key you provided on the command line

**value** = the file contents or the literal value you provided on the command line.

More about how to use it in pod [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

---

**Helm**

---

As @Matt mentionted in comments you can use helm

> [helm](https://helm.sh/) lets you template the yaml with values. Also once you get into it there are ways to create and include [partial templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/) – Matt

By the way, helm has it's own created [minio chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/minio), you might take a look how it is created there.

---

**Kustomize**

---

It's well described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/wordpress/README.md) and [here](https://blog.stack-labs.com/code/kustomize-101/)  how could you do that in kustomize.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I will go for the helm partial templates. I am already writing helm templates for another service. I did not think of using partial templates to solve this problem (well, I'm a newbie user of helm). Thanks for the advices. It might that I even couple two of the above options together.

Answer (score 0):

So, long story short: to solve my problem, I first created a new chart for my service and transformed the k8s manifests I had into helm templates. Then, I completed the `_helpers.tpl` with the following code:

```
{{/*
Common minio environment variables setup
*/}}
{{- define "minio.envvarsblock" -}}
- name: MINIO_SERVER_ACCESS_KEY
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: {{ .Values.minio.fullname }}
      key: access-key
- name: MINIO_SERVER_SECRET_KEY
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: {{ .Values.minio.fullname }}
      key: secret-key
- name: MINIO_SERVER_HOST
  value: {{ .Values.minio.fullname }}
- name: MINIO_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER
  value: {{ .Values.minio.server.port | quote }}
- name: MINIO_ALIAS
  value: {{ .Values.minio.client.alias }}
{{- end -}}

{{/*
Wait for minio init container definition
*/}}
{{- define "wait-for-minio" -}}
- name: wait-for-minio
  image: {{ .Values.minio.client.image }}
  env: {{- include "minio.envvarsblock" . | nindent 4 }}
  command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |
      mc config host add ${MINIO_ALIAS} http://${MINIO_SERVER_HOST}:${MINIO_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER} ${MINIO_SERVER_ACCESS_KEY} ${MINIO_SERVER_SECRET_KEY}
{{- end -}}
```

The first section above allows to reuse the `env` section throughout all my templates and the second allows to reuse an `initContainer` that I use all over the place too. I was then able to inject those partial templates into my helm templates like so (to take the example I put in my original post):

```
{{- if .Values.fixtures.enabled -}}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ include "chart.fullname" . }}-init-fixtures
  labels:
{{ include "chart.labels" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
      {{- include "wait-for-minio" . | nindent 6 }}
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-init-fixtures
        image: {{ .Values.image }}
        env: {{- include "minio.envvarsblock" . | nindent 10 }}
        command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - |
            mc config host add ${MINIO_ALIAS} http://${MINIO_SERVER_HOST}:${MINIO_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER} ${MINIO_SERVER_ACCESS_KEY} ${MINIO_SERVER_SECRET_KEY}

            for category in `ls`; do
              for f in `ls $category/*` ; do
                mc cp $f ${MINIO_ALIAS}/$category/$(basename $f)
              done
            done
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
{{- end -}}
```